# Tricky function for a VBA newbie

Tags: function, vba, excel-2010

Here's my problem. I need to compare 2 sets of cells on 2 different worksheet.

On sheet 1, cells A1 and A2. 
On sheet 2, cells A1 and A2.

On sheet 1, each cells will be populated by a single digit number, one being greater than the other, eg: 1-2, 2-1, 3-1, etc. and NEVER equal to another.

On sheet 2, only one of the cell will be populated with a single digit number. The other cell will always be empty.

I need to determine if the non empty cell on sheet 2 is the same cell as the cell on sheet 1 containing the greater number.

Unfortunatly I have next to 0 knowledge of VBA, trying to learn from tutorial but I can't seem to figure out how to write that one. Could someone help me please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Set Sh1 = Worksheets("First")
    Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Second")
    Dim iValue1 As Long
    If Sh1.Cells(2, 1) > Sh1.Cells(1, 1) Then
        iValue1 = Sh1.Cells(2, 1)
    Else
        iValue1 = Sh1.Cells(1, 1)
    End If
    Dim iValue2 As Long
    If Len(Sh2.Cells(2, 1)) = 0 Then
        iValue2 = Sh2.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        iValue2 = Sh2.Cells(2, 1)
    End If
    If iValue1 = iValue2 Then
        MsgBox "Equal"
    Else
        MsgBox "Different"
    End If
End Sub
```